# Pegando dados de um Json e salvando em outro [Perl]

Tags: json, perl

Boa noite, gostaria de saber se existe a forma de pegar dados de um json e salvar em outro de uma forma automática sem precisar tratar o json como "texto" (regex) no caso, já usei o módulo JSON do perl ( use JSON; ) mas foi para uma utilidade mais simples, já fiz algumas buscas e não encontrei nada parecido com isso que preciso.

o json que eu vou "tirar" as informações é dessa forma :

```
[{"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)","price":1292,"have":10,"max":28},{"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)","price":3769,"have":4,"max":13}]
```

Eu gostaria de passar apenas as entradas que estão dentro de "name" e "price", ficando mais ou menos assim :

```
{"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)":"13.16",
"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)":"37.64"}]
```

Já consegui alguma coisa tratando o json como texto, porém não está ficando "bom" como está lidando com o arquivo. 
Qualquer exemplo ou ideia já é bem vindo para eu começar a procurar como resolver.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com Perl + Módulo JSON:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use JSON;
my $j = '[
  {"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
   "price":1292,
   "have":10,
   "max":28},
  {"name":"AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)",
   "price":3769,
   "have":4,
   "max":13}]';

my  $v=from_json($j);
print to_json( {map {($_->{name},$_->{price})}  @$v });
```

Já agora outra alternativa comando `jq`

```
$ cat x.json | jq 'map([ .name , .price])'
[
  [
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
    1292
  ],
  [
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)",
    3769
  ]
]
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, na verdade resolveu duas coisas que eu precisava fazer com a opção do Perl.

Comment: @edufgimenez, otimo! obrigado.